# How to connect to SQLite database from virtual machine (VMWare)

Tags: database, sqlite, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a Win8 system (system A) with a WinXP VM (system B) running on it.

How to connect to SQLite database from virtual machine?

lets say my database on C:\mydatabase.db on machine A

Answer (score 1):

You can use file sharing to make some directory of the host available in the VM.